# How can I export cookies with httponly flag from Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-10

It seems that Internet Explorer doesn't export cookies that are flagged as httponly.
Example: JSESSIONID-Cookie from J2EE web applications.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: @Iorus see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7971/NET-Interactions-with-j2EE-based-Web-Applications may be help. I think browsers are able to process headers http. ))

Comment: I don't want to learn more about httponly flag, I already know that it is for disabling access for client side scripts to the cookie ... but I want them to appear in the export file when I do File -> Import/Export -> Cookies